# How to link react component to html?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to load react component from another js file, but i am not able to link that file...it says reference error..ads is not defined..I don't know how to solve this....i am doing this in django and react is also working fine.

//home.html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/home.css' %}" type="text/css"/>
     <script src="{% static 'root/react.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'root/react-dom.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'root/browser.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'javascript/ads.js' %}"></script>
</head>
<body id="root">
<script type="text/babel">
    class Home extends React.Component{
        render(){
            return(
                <div id="home">
                    <Header/>
                    <div id="container">
                        <div id="left">
                            <User/>
                            <Foo/>
                        </div>
                        <Post/>
                        <div id="right">
                            <Tranding/>
                            <Ads/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="upload">
                        <img src="{% static 'images/large.jpg' %}"/>
                        <div id="caption">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Write a caption"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

// ads.js

```
export class Ads extends React.Component{
        render(){
            return(<div id="ads">
                <div id="head">Ads</div>
            </div>)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you export the `Ads` class?

Comment: Yes I tried it but nothing seems to be working...I tried export default also and got same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using import in your script.  You are trying to use the script tag to import... this does not work the same way.  You should instead either `import Ads from 'javascript/ads.js'` or you leave the script inclusion and instead in your `ads.js` file attach `window.Ads = Ads`

Also, do not forget to use export syntax properly.  It would be `export default class Ads` not `export class Ads`

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure Ads class is exported from ads.js.

Comment: You need to export default for one.  Also, it does not look like you are using imports correctly.  If you are going to just use a reference like this you need to `window.Ads = Ads` instead of exporting.